# Ruby: How do I remove nil/empty values from a nested hash and why aren't my attempts doing so?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm trying to write a method that removes all keys in a nested hash that point to nil recursively.

For example:

```rb
{:a=>nil, :b=>"b", :c=>nil, :d=>{:dd=>"dd", :ee=>nil, :ff=>"ff"}, :e=>{:gg=>nil, :hh=>nil}}
```

becomes:

```rb
{:b=>"b", :d=>{:dd=>"dd", :ff=>"ff"}}
```

I'm not having much luck though.

My most recent attempt looks like:

```rb
def deep_compact(hash)
  hash.reject do |key, value|
    deep_compact(value) if value.class == Hash
    next true if value.nil? || value.empty?
  end
end
```

Here I want to iterate over each key value pair in the hash. If the value is a hash, I want to do the same for that hash. I want to reject the pair if the value is nil or empty. Otherwise, I want to keep it.

The result isn't what I want:

```rb
#=> {:b=>"b", :d=>{:dd=>"dd", :ee=>nil, :ff=>"ff"}, :e=>{:gg=>nil, :hh=>nil}}
```

I have also tried:

```rb
def deep_compact(hash)
  hash.compact.transform_values do |value|
    deep_compact(value) if value.class == Hash
    value
  end
end
```

Again, I get the same result:

```rb
#=> {:b=>"b", :d=>{:dd=>"dd", :ee=>nil, :ff=>"ff"}, :e=>{:gg=>nil, :hh=>nil}}
```

This leaves me to believe that either I've missed something or my understanding of recursion is wrong.

Are any of my attempts close? What do I need to do to ensure I get the result I want: `{:b=>"b", :d=>{:dd=>"dd", :ff=>"ff"}}`?

Answer (score 1):

The trick would be to recursively compact nested hashes and then to eliminate empty values.

```
compact = ->(hash) { 
  hash.is_a?(Hash) ?
    hash.map { |k, v| [k, compact.(v)] }.
         to_h.
         delete_if { |_, v| v.nil? || v.respond_to?(:empty?) && v.empty? } :
    hash 
}
compact.(input)
#⇒ {:b=>"b", :d=>{:dd=>"dd", :ff=>"ff"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that by placing my recursive function call at the end of the block got me most of the way there. (Is this 'tail-end' recursion?)

I also call `reject` on the hash returned by `transform_values` to removed any empty pairs.

This achieves what I wanted:

```rb
def deep_compact(hash)
  hash.compact.transform_values do |value|
    next value unless value.class == Hash
    deep_compact(value)
  end.reject { |_k, v| v.empty? }
end
```

```sh
> h
=> {:a=>nil, :b=>"b", :c=>nil, :d=>{:dd=>"dd", :ee=>nil, :ff=>"ff"}, :e=>{:gg=>nil, :hh=>nil}}
> deep_compact h
=> {:b=>"b", :d=>{:dd=>"dd", :ff=>"ff"}}
```

Comment: `value.class == Hash` should be `value.class <= Hash` or better `value.is_a?(Hash)`, otherwise the code would fail on any `Hash` descendant, like `Hashie::Mash`. Also, first immediate `compact` is redundant, just use `v.nil? || v.empty?` in `reject`.

Comment: _"Is this 'tail-end' recursion?"_ – no, because `deep_compact` is not the last expression in your method.

Comment: _“Is this 'tail-end' recursion?”_ — it does matter much actually because MRI has TCO off by default (though one might turn it on.)

Answer (score 0):

Other option using [Hash#reject!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-reject-21), it changes the original Hash:

```
def deep_compact(h)
  h.each { |_, v| deep_compact(v) if v.is_a? Hash }.reject! { |_, v| v.nil? || v.empty? }
end

deep_compact(h)
#=> {:b=>"b", :d=>{:dd=>"dd", :ff=>"ff"}}
```